# How to process a JPEG binary data in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, mat

I am trying to process a JPEG Binary data in OpenCV. When I do that I get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.

I read JPEG file through `fread` command and stored in a buffer.

After reading, I copied the buffer data to a `Mat` variable, 
When I tried to do grayscale conversion on copied data using `cvtColor` OpenCV function. I get Segmentation Fault.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat threshold_output;
    Mat gray_image;

    unsigned char *pre_image;
    FILE *read_image;
    FILE *write_image;
    int filesize;
    size_t data, write;

    read_image = fopen(argv[1] , "rb"); //Read Jpeg as Binary
    write_image = fopen("output11.jpg", "wb"); //Write JPEG

    if(read_image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Image Not Found\r\n");
    }
    fseek(read_image, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileLen = ftell(read_image);
    fseek(read_image, 0, SEEK_SET);

    pre_image = (unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen);
    data = fread(pre_image, 1, fileLen, read_image);
    write = fwrite(pre_image, 1, fileLen, write_image);

    // Printed and verify the values
    printf("File Size %d\r\n", fileLen);
    printf("Read bytes %zu\r\n", data);
    printf("Write bytes %zu\r\n", data);

    fclose(read_image);
    fclose(write_image);

    /* Copy the Jpeg Binary buffer to a MAt Variable*/  
    cv::Mat image(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3, pre_image); //Seg Fault comes here
    /* Convert Grayscale */
    cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    /* Threshold conversion */
    threshold( gray_image, threshold_output, 80, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

    namedWindow( "Thresholded", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Thresholded", image );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I have attached the code for reference. I have verified that both `fread` and `fwrite` works properly. 
But when I do the `cvtColor` only I got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Micka already pointed out, you should use [cv::imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode)

You can use it with your `FILE*`. You probably may want to use `fstreams` if you're using C++. You can also rely directly on OpenCV capabilities to read files.

The code below will show you these options for reading files. Code for writing is similar (I can add it if you need it).

Remember that if you want to write the binary stream, you should use [imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode)

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    ////////////////////////////////
    // Method 1: using FILE*
    ////////////////////////////////

    FILE* read_image = fopen("path_to_image", "rb");
    if (read_image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Image Not Found\n");
    }

    fseek(read_image, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileLen = ftell(read_image);
    fseek(read_image, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char* pre_image = (unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen);
    size_t data = fread(pre_image, 1, fileLen, read_image);

    // Printed and verify the values
    printf("File Size %d\n", fileLen);
    printf("Read bytes %d\n", data);

    fclose(read_image);

    vector<unsigned char> buffer(pre_image, pre_image + data);
    Mat img = imdecode(buffer, IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);

    ////////////////////////////////
    //// Method 2: using fstreams
    ////////////////////////////////

    //ifstream ifs("path_to_image", iostream::binary);
    //filebuf* pbuf = ifs.rdbuf();
    //size_t size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0, ifs.end, ifs.in);
    //pbuf->pubseekpos(0, ifs.in);
    //vector<char> buffer(size);
    //pbuf->sgetn(buffer.data(), size);
    //ifs.close();
    //Mat img = imdecode(buffer, IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);


    ////////////////////////////////
    //// Method 3: using imread
    ////////////////////////////////

    //Mat img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);


    // Work with img as you want

    imshow("img", img);
    waitKey();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Miki... I can able to decode using your code.. And Thanks for the changes you made.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses channels like BGR etc and can't perform computer vision operations on ENCODED images, since encoded images don't consist of pixel data but some encoded data which can be transformed to pixels. OpenCV assumes that images are already decoded so it can work on pixel data.

BUT: you can use a binary image buffer (like your `pre_image`) and let openCV DECODE it.

use `cv::imdecode` to do it and after that you'll get a legal `cv::Mat` image.  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you help me in using that imdecode in my program. I am very new to opencv. I know to use some simple opencv functions. I am not so familiar with this one.

Comment: answer of @Miki provides sample code. The important lines are: `vector<unsigned char> buffer(pre_image, pre_image + data);
    Mat img = imdecode(buffer, IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);`

Comment: and please, if you really get your image data from files (so your jpeg image isnt already in a buffer) use `cv::Mat input = cv::imread(filename);` (which decodes the image/jpeg, too, if necessary) directly and don't care about reading the file manually etc! (as @Miki mentioned, too)

Comment: Thank you sir... I can able to decode and use the Pixels