# Opencv: imdecode() is failed for images with non standard sizes

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, jpeg

I met one feature for cv::imdecode() - when I tried to load the image with  with non standard size, I always got the image with  a NULL buffer and rows = 0.

For example, here is a .jpg with size 236x402:

[image]

My C++ code:

```
FILE* pf = NULL;
pf = _wfopen(strFileName, L"r");
if (!pf)
{
    return false;
}
fread(pFileBuf, 1, nFileSize, pf);
fclose(pf);
cv::Mat matRaw = cv::Mat( 1, nFileSize, CV_8UC1, pFileBuf);
cv::Mat matImage = cv::imdecode(matRaw, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
delete [] pFileBuf;
SIZE size;
size.cx = matImage.cols;
size.cy = matImage.rows;
```

After run matImage.rows = 0 and matImage.data = NULL.

But for an jpeg image with 1280x720 it works well.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you try to use `fopen` mode with "b" (binary) included (`L"rb"`)? If you use just "r", then the default mode depends on value in some variable, so using "b" for opening image files is safer (doesn't depend on any variable and all image files I know have binary structure).

Comment: what is the type of pFileBuf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process a JPEG binary data in OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831210/how-to-process-a-jpeg-binary-data-in-opencv)

Comment: Have a look at _"Method 1"_ in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31832427/5008845)

Comment: For Ped7g, I corrected  on "rb" and  the problem went away.  Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The bug in

```
pf = _wfopen(strFileName, L"r");
```

Must be

```
pf = _wfopen(strFileName, L"rb");
```

Thank for help